# Bookdown raising error 83 after update - no line number shown (osX)

Tags: bookdown, gitbook

I just updated my version of bookdown/RStudio to the latest version.
Unfortunately, now I have some problems in the code debug on my own. More precisely, this error message that I am getting lacks a line number in any Rmd file.

```
Error running filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/bookdown/rmarkdown/lua/custom-environment.lua:
...es/library/bookdown/rmarkdown/lua/custom-environment.lua:192: bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
    ...es/library/bookdown/rmarkdown/lua/custom-environment.lua:192: in function 'Div'
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Any idea on how to proceed from here?

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331617/trying-to-knit-rmarkdown-but-getting-pandoc-utils-error-or-pandoc-error-83) did not help, as typing in the Console of Rstudio, if I type:

  Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")

  "/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin"

which is the correct location of pandoc.

Comment: not a solution to your problem, but you might want to look into `renv` to avoid this type of issue next time around